# Using mongodb tools (mongodump, mongorestore) from another machine

Tags: linux, backup, backup-restoration, mongodb

I have a mongodb server (A) and a http server (B). I would like to run mongodump and mongorestore commands on http server (B) to backup data on server B. But these tools comes with mongodb installation and i don't want to install mongodb to my http server.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You mean you don't want to download the binaries? There's no need to "install" mongodb as a package of your distro

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: ubuntu-debian installed via: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Comment: apt-get install mongodb-clients (or sudo apt-get install mongodb-clients) worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 when needing just the client and not the 'weight' of the full install. I know we're not talking about much of a footprint but I tend to subscribe to the 'only what you need' model of server admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10gen doesn't provide seperate packages such as server - clients - dev & doc for mongodb (at least I couldn't found for Ubuntu 10.04). So I just copied /usr/bin/mongodump and /usr/bin/mongorestore binaries to my HTTP server manually (machines were same architecture) Now i'm running these commands on my server which doesn't have any mongodb installation without problems.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is quite an old question, but googling took me there. On ubuntu 14.04 I have a following line in `/etc/sources.list.d/mongo.list` to have the 3.2 version there:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
```

The source contains few packages. According to the [MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#packages) it's like this:

- `mongodb-org` - A metapackage that will automatically install the four component packages listed below.
- `mongodb-org-server` - Contains the mongod daemon and associated configuration and init scripts.
- `mongodb-org-mongos` - Contains the mongos daemon.
- `mongodb-org-shell` - Contains the mongo shell.
- `mongodb-org-tools` - Contains the following MongoDB tools: mongoimport bsondump, mongodump, mongoexport, mongofiles, mongooplog, mongoperf, mongorestore, mongostat, and mongotop.

So in your case the `mongodb-org-tools` should be enough.

Answer (score 6):

Usually Linux distributions create several packages from a single software, like server, clients, dev and doc.

For example, on Debian, you can install the mongodb-clients package that contains mongodump and mongorestore and does not install the mongodb server.

Answer (score 4):

For those installing on Amazon Ubuntu on EC2 using the 10gen yum repository for MongoDB, I had to `sudo yum install mongo-10gen.x86_64` to get `mongo`, `mongodump`, `mongorestore` and `mongos`.

Don't forget you can always `sudo yum search mongo`...